# How to convert data type with too many columns in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

Now, I have a data like this:

```
data = 
    foreach data 
    generate
        flatten(STRSPLIT(feature, ',', -1));
```

If `flatten(STRSPLIT(feature, ',', -1));` only have 2 columns, I know  we can convert the data type of each column to `float` like this:

```
data_new = 
    foreach data 
    generate
        (float)$0,
        (float)$1;
```

However, if `flatten(STRSPLIT(feature, ',', -1));` has `500` columns, I know it is impossible to convert data type like the following:

```
data_new = 
    foreach data 
    generate
        (float)$0,
        (float)$1,
        (float)$2,
        .......,
        .......,
        (float)$498,
        (float)$499;
```

I'm new to Pig, may I ask if there is a way to convert data type when `flatten(STRSPLIT(feature, ',', -1));` has `500` columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No easy way to do it.One workaround is to write an UDF and pass the string.Split the string in the udf and prefix every field with (float) and concat to get back the string with (float) as prefix in front of each column.Finally  use STRSPLIT on the returned string.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Thanks a lot! I'll try it.